# Openlayers get boundingbox around circle in cluster layer

Tags: openlayers, extents

I have a cluster layer which contains circles. Each circle contains some number of features. I need to get the smallest bounding box for a circle when it's clicked. If I could get the center and radius of each circle onclick, that would solve my problem too, but I can't seem to find an obvious way to do that.

How can I get a bounding box for an element in a cluster layer, or the center and radius of that element?

Here's my cluster layer.

```
  var clusterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    id: 'clusterLayer',
    source: clusterSource,
    style: function addClusterStyle(feature) {
      var size = feature.get('features').length;
      var pointRadius = 8 + (size.toString().length * 2);
      var style = styleCache[size];
      if (!style) {
        style = [
          new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
              radius: pointRadius,
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#ff0000'
              }),
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffb3b3'
              })
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
              text: size.toString(),
              font: 'bold 12px arial,sans-serif',
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'black'
              })
            })
          })
        ];
        styleCache[size] = style;
      }
      map.removeInteraction(draw);
      return style;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get a bounding box around the features within the circle on cluster layer rather than a bounding box around the circle itself. I have access to the features within the circle so I can use the following:

```
var cFeatures = popupfeature.feature.get('features');

// if there are more than 4 items in the map pin, include a link to view all of them
if (cFeatures.length > 4) {
    // get the coordinates of all features in the cluster
    var featureCoords = cFeatures.map(x => x.getGeometry().getCoordinates());

    // get the min and max coordinates
    var maxX = featureCoords.map(x => x[0]).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.max(a, b);
    });
    var maxY = featureCoords.map(x => x[1]).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.max(a, b);
    });
    var minX = featureCoords.map(x => x[0]).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.min(a, b);
    });
    var minY = featureCoords.map(x => x[1]).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.min(a, b);
    });

    // convert to lat long
    var minCoord = ol.proj.transform([minX, minY], dstProj, srcProj);
    var maxCoord = ol.proj.transform([maxX, maxY], dstProj, srcProj);

    var textToRest = "See all " + cFeatures.length;
    var linkToRest = textToRest.link(homeURL + 'search/Results?type=AllFields&filter[]=long_lat:Intersects(ENVELOPE(' + [minCoord[0], maxCoord[0], maxCoord[1], minCoord[1]].join(",%20") + '))');
    // open link in new tab (inster targe=_blank after <a)
    linkToRest = linkToRest.slice(0,2) + " target='_blank' " + linkToRest.slice(2);
    pcontent += linkToRest;
}
```

While this does work, it doesn't always create an even square around the cluster. It is also quite inefficient for larger clusters since I iterate over every feature in the cluster.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Or a way to make sure the bounding box is around the cluster rather than the items within the cluster?